ms sql (2016) выполняет один и тот же запрос с разной скоростью
Есть экз ms sql 2016, 12 ядер, 480 гб память (на сервере 512гб). 4 контроллера 8 дисков ssd. Отчет, сделанный на sap BO формирует запрос.  БД примерно 7 тб. Таблица с данными содержит 3 млрд строк. Пополняется ежедневно. По состоянию на первое число месяца приходит около 7-8 млн строк. В остальные дни в 4 раз меньше. Отчет выбирает данные за тек месяц и на начало года. Работает несколько секунд. Но когда приходят данные на первое число примерно неделю выбирает данные примерно за 70-80 минут. Потом снова быстро. Статистика обновляется автоматом. Ключ 2371 поднят. Руками статистику на таблицу с данными, таблицы со справочниками на фулл скан обновлял. Кэш процедур для подготовки плана запроса очищал. Ничего не помогает. Где и куда копать? Буду признателен за идеи. Евгений.

пробовали партиционирование таблицы?

А план запроса что говорит?

Не разобрался как здесь ответить персонально. Отвечу общим ответом. Партицирование делать пытались, недостаток опыта и таблицу разбили неудачно. Сейчас такой возможности практически нет. Нужен серьезный ресурс. такая работа пока в планах. План запроса не такой простой, как и запрос. Если видели запросы BI к базе вы поймете. У плана порядка 10 цепочек по которым собираются данные. Видно что в медленном случае случае выбирается лишний раз порядка 1,8 млн строк но что за это отвечает не могу определить. не настолько глубокие знания.

Вообще план имеет смысл смотреть хотя бы для того, что если не хватает каких-то очевидных индексов, то SSMS сам предложит их создать, когда будет показывать план выполнения запроса. А так в общем без конкретики можно только что-то общее советовать. Индексы недостающие сделать. Партиционирование. Может какие-то временные таблицы в процессе выполнения запроса создавать для промежуточных данных. Иногда и такое помогает.

CrazyElf, план запроса, особенно сложный план есть смысл смотреть когда понимаешь и можешь делать правильные выводы. Про индексы согласен в некоторой степени. С остальным - нет. Смотрите, ситуация следующая. 1 июня: работает долго за первое июня. 1 июля: работает долго на первое июля. А вот на первое июня работает уже секунды. Это значит, что индексов хватает. Может не хватает статистик (допустим не успели обновиться)? Проверяем путем обновления ВСЕХ статистик по всем строкам (full scan). Проверяем скорость - не помогло.  И сейчас вопрос: Что еще?

А по мне это значит, что когда выбран текущий месяц, то считается какая-то другая, объёмная статистика. Может даже именно когда 1-е число. Может это даже ошибка какая-то в запросе. Нужно смотреть конкретику, на мой взгляд. Может там вообще какие-то аггрегаты считаются со временем и статистика берётся из них потом, а 1-го числа этих аггрегатов ещё нет и статистика считается по сырым данным. Я могу тучу вариантов придумать, почему так. Без конкретных данных и запроса тут только гадать.

Как работает отчет я знаю. Ничего там дополнительно не считается. Только то что я написал. Похоже ситуация решилась. Обратил внимание, что запрос, будучи запущенным из sql-студии возваращает предупреждение типа "Неправильная оценка кардинальности".  Нашел на эту тему статью  https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/performance/cardinality-estimation-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Изучил код запроса. Еще раз повторю, строится он BI-средством автоматически на основе объектов промежуточного слоя. Нашел в нем такой предикат ( dbo.Cell_Warehouse_View.IndexId <> 31  ) В соответствии со статьей исправил на ( dbo.Cell_Warehouse_View.IndexId > 31  ) соответствующий объект пром слоя. Это все. Отчет заработал.
